# How can I get the serial number printed on RFID tag with RFID reader?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, number-formatting, rfid

How can I get the serial number printed on an RFID tag through an RFID reader?

I have:

- Arduino uno,
- RMD 6300 reader, and
- RFID tag (125Khz).

I use the following code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial RFID(2, 3); // RX and TX

int i;

void setup()
{
  RFID.begin(9600);    // start serial to RFID reader
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial to PC 
}

void loop()
{
  if (RFID.available() > 0) 
  {
     i = RFID.read();
     Serial.print(i, DEC);
     Serial.print(" ");
  }
}
```

I get this value:

```
2 48 57 48 48 50 69 52 69 65 50 67 66 3
```

But the following value is printed on the RFID tag:

```
0003034786
```

I would want to have this number, but I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: possible way I guess ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848921/arduino-rfid-checksum-calculation-and-key-visualization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that you currently get is the serial number encoded as US-ASCII string. The value in decimal (as you currently print it) is

```
2 48 57 48 48 50 69 52 69 65 50 67 66 3
```

Converting these bytes into hexadecimal form (for better readability) leads to:

```
02 30 39 30 30 32 45 34 45 41 32 43 42 03
```

Encoding these bytes in [US-ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) leads to this string:

```
<STX>09002E4EA2CB<ETX>
```

Note that you could also receive this form directly on your console by using

```
Serial.write(i);
```

instead of `Serial.print(i, DEC);`

Thus, your reader starts outputting the serial number by sending a start-of-transmission (STX) character (0x02) and ends sending the serial number with an end-of-transmission (ETX) character. Everything in between is the serial number (represented as hexadecimal characters):

```
09002E4EA2CB
```

The serial number printed on your key (0003034786) is only a fraction of the complete serial number. This value is the decimal representation. If you convert

```
0003034786
```

to its hexadecimal representation, you get

```
002E4EA2
```

This value is contained in the serial number that you received from the reader:

```
09002E4EA2CB
```

Therefore, you could do something like this to print the value (use `sprintf()`, if you need the leading zeros):

```
void loop() {
    int serialNumber = 0;
    int charIndex = 0;
    int currentChar;

    if (RFID.available() > 0) {
        currentChar = RFID.read();
        ++charIndex;
        if (currentChar == 0x002) {
            charIndex = 0;
            serialNumber = 0;
        } else if (currentChar == 0x003) {
            Serial.print(serialNumber, DEC);
            Serial.print(" ");
        } else {
            if ((charIndex >= 1) && (charIndex < 5)) {
                serialNumber <<= 8;
                serialNumber += currentChar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```